# What document is Play Store expecting me to upload to show that I'm not impersonating others?

Tags: android, google-play

My company is currently making an Android application for a local $BigCarManufacturer dealer. We are not impersonating anyone, the application is under the name of "$BigCarManufacturer $dealer", and we even cooperated with some guys from $BigCarManufacturer to provide us some web services from their official website. Unfortunately, the application was immediately suspended for impersonation, and now I can only appeal the removal. When I do, I get the option to upload some documents, and the following message:

> If you selected Intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior above, please provide a document that proves you have the rights to use specific content, icons, images, etc.

So what exactly is expected here? The scans of the contract? In what language? The contract doesn't exist in English, and is pretty trivial otherwise, basically "make an app for us, we'll pay you X, and use anything you need from our website". No one was anal enough to specify individual icons, images or anything silly like that since none of those rights were transferred to us in the first place, we are merely using assets to build an app *for them*.

Comment: @aug - we'll, it's a similar situation, but that guy seems to be in actual violation, and the one (unaccepted) answer is not applicable.

Comment: Facing same problem, still not have idea what document to submit.

Comment: oka y the simple contract is not enough.. go back to client with Trademark and Ip release agreement and have the client sign that and than upload it. If you ask a local lawyer they will have such a template form to use

Comment: @FredGrott..Thanks I will do that..I dont think there is any other option.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have any documentation binding you to that name? If that's not enough then send them a link to your website which I imagine should have some sort of house style. If you prove that your brand is recognizable and does not look familiar to ones of a similar name you should be clear to proceed.
Hope this helps
p.s What is the service you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. We're a software manufacturing company, and we are making an app for, let's hypothetically call them "Tom's Mercedes Saloon". "Tom's Mercedes Saloon" is an official Mercedes dealer for the region, and all the app branding is theirs and Mercedes's. My company isn't mentioned anywhere, and Google is accusing us of impersonation.

Comment: Apologies if I hadn't been clear. I understand that, all I am saying is, if you have a company logo, website and anything else that clearly shows you are unique, send google services an email informing them of where you currently stand and the link to your website, the image of your logo and any documents such as copyrighting. If you still struggle to get anywhere, ask them exactly what they want as proof and if that's still not enough, appeal the decision

Comment: Ah, OK. At the moment, the Play Store account itself is linked to our company and website, and hosts multiple apps we've made in the past for our clients. I'm not sure if it is gonna help, but we'll see. I'm waiting for the contracts to be scanned anyway, and communicating with the "Mercedes" representative to see if we could produce some formal document that specifically states we are allowed to use their brand in this way.

Comment: @Davor..I am also facing same issue.. Have you managed to resolve the problem?

Comment: @SagarShirke - yo, sorry for not coming back to say how it worked out. In the end, we just scanned the contract in my native language, and a single passage "statement" by the dealer saying they give authorisation to our company to use all their assets in development. The app got unblocked, and we had no further communication from Google.

Comment: @Davor..Thanks for your comment..but in my case no contract is available directly because it is my client's client whoes logo we are using.So wanted to know what other options are there..We can contact Client's client and upload any html documen on there site.. but getting any contract information same as your case is diiificult..